# How to display a view as a popup view or like an alert view in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, popup

I want to display a view  with two text field and a button. I want to pop the view like an alert view. Just like how Facebook is popping up and asking for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The UIAlertView will accept `addTextFieldWithValue:label:`, but this is an undocumented API and may cause Apple to reject your app.  There was a discussion in the iPhoneDevSDK.com forums about this with some sample code to do the same in an acceptable manner.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1704-uitextfield-inside-uialertview.html

Comment: i am not able set the frame size of the alert view, so i dropped it.I want the frame of the view to be 300x340.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to subclass UIAlertView and override the DrawRect: method. You can then resize the window, change its color, and anything inside. Hope it works out for you!

Edit: here is a link that i used a while back to give me a basic idea behind it. 
http://joris.kluivers.nl/iphone-dev/?p=CustomAlert